# android textview right-aligned rightmost text on LED Panel will have an extra column of pixels.Why?How to resolce it

Tags: android, textview, led

[bug on led](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UukMD.jpg)

As shown in the figure,the last text is not displayed properly,it has  an extra column of pixels.
This bug is only shown on Led Panel.
I want know why it occur and how to resolve it.
Seems like I would have seen this issue before on other led displays,but i see noone ask this question on google.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.